# Can someone help me trace this quote?

Tags: reference, verse, shankaracharya

The following is credited by Śrī Sanātana Gosvāmī in his Digdarśinī svaṭīkā on his Bṛhad-bhāgavatāmṛta as being a statement of Śrī Śaṅkarācārya:

> muktā api līlayā vigrahaṁ kṛtvā bhagavantaṁ bhajante

Śrī Svāmī Karapātrī quotes a slightly different version in his Bhagavattattva, as if the statement is being made to Bhagavān:

> muktā api līlayā vigrahaṁ kṛtvā te bhajante

Svāmī Karapātrī cites this verse as coming from the Nṛsiṃha Tāpanīyopaniṣad Bhāṣya, but he doesn't give a specific reference and I haven't been able to locate it yet. Does anyone know, if it does in fact originate from this source, where it is located? I've seen some other indications that it may actually have originated from Śrīdhara Svāmī's Śrīmad Bhagavata Bhāvārtha Dīpikā.

Dhanyavāda.